# Loading Texture2d content in Monogame

Tags: xna, monogame, xna-content-pipeline

I am using Monogame and following this tutorial series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=agt9-J9RPZ0

I am trying to load a Texture2d into the window and despite not getting any error messages the image is not shown.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Code @: https://github.com/blivori/TestGame

Solution setup:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You load the texture perfectly, but I don't see any code regarding the drawing of it. Add this:

`spriteBatch.Draw(image, new Vector(0f, 0f), Color.White);`

into your SplashScreen's Draw function.

Comment: I didn't see your answer before posting mine (deleted). Can't believe this took 83 views and 4 days... and you beat me by 19 hours! :)

Comment: If it has solved your problem, please mark as solution and the bounty.